# Unable to create DataCacheFactory instance in debug

Tags: c#, caching, azure

- I'm working on web project that will run on Windows Azure Web role;
- In the cloud, there will be 2 instances of the role;
- I'm using co-located named cache (In-Role Cache) spread between 2 role instances;
- Locally, I debug with single instance;
- In the cloud, cache client is created successfully and work fluently;
- When debug locally, I am unable to create instance of DataCacheFactory, because when the constructor is called, the program flow "stops" and doesn't continue to the following statement. There is no exception!

That's the code where I'm creating Factory and cache client:

```
var cacheFactoryConfig = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration
        {
            ChannelOpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
            TransportProperties = {ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45)}
        };
        DataCacheFactory cacheFactory;
        try
        {
            cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory(cacheFactoryConfig);// <--stops here
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("--> Message-> {0}; --> Stack Trace->{1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace));
            throw;
        }
cacheClient = cacheFactory.GetDefaultCache();
```

Service configuration:
[image: Service Configuration]

Cache client and server configuration in web.config
[image: Cache client and server configuration in web.config]

I would give any additional information if such is requested in order to resolve the problem shortly.

------EDIT 1------------------

Due to related post [Making Windows Azure Caching Work in Compute Emulator](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/08/07/making-windows-azure-caching-work-in-compute-emulator/) I have to add some info:

- Operating sistem -> Windows 7 Professional
- IDE -> Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 4
- Windows Azure Caching package 2.4.0.0
- Windows Azure SDK Version 2.4

I don't have Windows Server AppFabric installed, so I'm going for it!

Comment: Do you see anything in the debug output window in Visual Studio?

Comment: - "A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsFabric.Common.dll"  was thrown when cacheFactoryConfig object was created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of investigation, I managed to solve the issue and successfully create instance of DataCacheFactory and DataCache and so on. The problem is described and solved in the following **2 posts**:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8580689a-a1a1-4db7-bba9-f42c1a90e0db/windows-azure-webrole-caching-preview-hangs-makes-the-emulator-stuck-in-deploy-loop?forum=windowsazuredevelopment

http://blog.elastacloud.com/2012/06/09/using-the-windows-azure-cache-preview-with-sdk-1-7/

- In my case, I had Microsoft Server AppFabric installed, so I removed it.
- Just in case, I removed all available Windows Azure SDKs (2.4 was installed) and 
  all old nuget packages related to Azure Caching.
- I did verify that all assemblies are removed from GAC too.
- After "cleaning" I install again latest Azure SDK available which is 2.5. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-in-role/

I would like to point out, that windows Event Viewer helped a lot. In Windows Azure logs I found an error that was happening when I start the web role with Azure Emulator. Error was thrown by CacheInstaller.exe -> MissingMethodExceprion with message:

> Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.ClusterConfigElement

Comment: Yeah I ran into this, too... really anoying. But anyways, AppFabric or Azure cache is sh... ;) Use Redis instead. You can run Redis on your Azure cluster as well and it seems to be much faster